# spring boot tests with liquibase + h2 fails - not able to find information_schema

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mariadb, h2, liquibase, spring-boot-test

I am trying to run a spring boot test for one of the config file, I am using mariadb as my main db but h2 in memory database for tests and liquibase for migration. When I run the test I am seeing below error

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "STATISTICS" not found; SQL statement:
`select count(*) from information_schema.statistics where table_schema='TEST_MY_APP' and index_name='UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_MY_IDX' [42102-214]`
```

It is not able to find information_schema in h2 DB and by default it is looking for TEST_MY_APP schema.

I have above SQL statement in liquibase scripts.

I am using below code:

```
 @SpringBootTest 
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/test.properties")
 class MyAppConfigTest {
     @Autowired
     private MyAppConfig myAppConfig;
 
     @Test
     void verifyAppVersion() {
         assertEquals("devtest", myAppConfig.getAppVersion());
    } }
```

test.properties file:

```
app.version=devtest
myapp.db.password=sa
localMediaService.db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST_MY_APP
myapp.db.username=sa
myapp.db.database=H2
myapp.db.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
myapp.db.schemaName=TEST_MY_APP
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/myappservice/db-changelog-master.xml
spring.test.database.replace=none
# Both these properties required to get the defaultSchema into liquibase scripts.
spring.liquibase.defaultSchema=TEST_MY_APP
spring.liquibase.parameters.defaultSchema=TEST_MY_APP
```

dependencies used in build.gradle:

```
  implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2'
```

I tried adding DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MariaDB;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false; to the db url but none of them worked. I even tried replacing MODE=MySQL but that didn't work either. Please let me know If I am missing anything and if you have any suggestions/ideas to resolve this. Thanks.